# Regular Expression Required for Validating Decimal Numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Can someone please provide a regular expression that allows:

- Up to 18 digits before the decimal point
- Two digits after decimal point

Valid Values: 18.50, 5556.50
Invalid Values: 18.555, 5879.5877 etc.

Comment: Have you considered using `Decimal.TryParse` and then checking the upper bounds and precision? That would work with any user-configured culture and ensures that when parsing it, you get the same value. Regex is very suboptimal in this case. An ASP.NET Range Validator would allow a similar validation client side: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Just remember that what you call the decimal point `.`, is the thousands separator in The Netherlands and a number of other countries, where we use `,` to signal the fraction and `.` as a thousand separator. Regex is too fixed to properly support internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
\b\d{1,18}\.\d{1,2}\b
```

- `\b` captures word boundaries; if you enclose your regex between two `\b` you will restrict your search to words, i.e. text delimited by space, punctuations etc.
- `\d` captures digits
- `\d{1,18}` captures at least 1 digit and maximum 18 digits
- `\.` captures a dot; you have to prepend a backslash to escape the dot character because it is a special symbol for regex engines and it is used to capture everything
- `\d{1,2}` captures at least 1 digit and maximum 2 digits

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/EbXnlU/3), so you can test it as you please.

Comment: Bookmarked the link. Code generation for c# too! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To match up to 18 digits before the decimal point you could use `\d{1,18}`. To match 2 digits after the decimal point you could use `\d{2}`.

Your regex could then look like:

[`\b\d{1,18}\.\d{2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/CeaMjJ/1/)

That would match:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d{1,18}` Match a digits 1-18 times
- `\.` Match a dot
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `\b` Word boundary

Answer (score 0):

For validation inputs you don't need to use `\b` in your regex.

This would help you:

```
^\d{1,18}\.\d{1,2}$
```

With this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NIzpKZ/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Everyone! 
I think I have just developed something more simple than creating regular expressions. Here is what I did:

```
Dim mrp_point As Integer = 0
Dim mrp_decimal_count As Integer = 1
Private Sub txtMRP_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtMRP.KeyPress
    If mrp_decimal_count < 2 Then
        If mrp_point = 0 Then
            e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = "." Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8)
            If Not txtMRP.Text = "" Then
                Dim mrp As String = txtMRP.Text
                Dim last As Char = mrp(mrp.Length - 1)
                If last = "." Then
                    mrp_point = 1
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf mrp_point = 1 Then
            e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8)
            mrp_decimal_count = mrp_decimal_count + 1
        End If
    Else
        e.Handled = Not (e.KeyChar = " " Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8)
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyways, Thanks for your time and help! :)